# Função php de INSERT no banco mysql(checkbox)

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com dificuldades para fazer vários `INSERTS`.

Problema: estou desenvolvendo sistema que cadastra `tag` de funcionário em uma tabela mas não estou consigo fazer tudo de uma vez só.

Exemplo: gostaria de cadastrar um nome de uma pessoa, sua empresa e nome da tag em uma tabela no `mysql` exemplo:

(mateus,empresa,php)

(mateus,empresa,java)

(lucas,empresa,php)

(lucas,empresa,java)

como seria INSERT  nessa situaçao

```html
<form name="form" method="post" action="form.php">
<p>
<label for="nome">Nome:</label>
<input type="text" id="nome" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="empresa">empresa:</label>
<input type="text" id="empresa" />
</p>
<p>
<label>php</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="genero[]" value="php"/>
</p>
<p>
<label>java</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="genero[]" value="java"/>
</p>
<p>
<label>mysql</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="genero[]" value="mysql"/>
</p>
<p>
<label>Terror</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="genero[]" value="terror"/>
</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

form.php

```html
foreach ($_POST['genero'] as $value) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro que está faltando o `name` nos seus inputs de Nome e Empresa, você deve corrigir isso. Depois poderá criar um laço simples de `inserts` e execução de `querys`:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
foreach ($_POST['genero'] as $value) {
    $query = 'INSERT INTO tabela(nome, empresa, tag) VALUES({$nome}, {$empresa}, {$value})';
    //ou
    //$query = 'INSERT INTO tabela(nome, empresa, tag) VALUES('.$nome.', '.$empresa.', '.$value.')';
    // executa a query e vai para o próximo registro...
}
```